# Laravel ::get() returns models

Tags: laravel, model

My issue with laravel is that any data that I want to show returns a model instead of the data.

I migrated my database 4 times just to check if it wasn't an error inside the database, tinker returns models aswell.

**My Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::get();
        dd($products);
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

**My model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'Product_name',
        'Product_image',
        'Product_price',
        'Store_ID'
    ];
}
```

**My blade**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    {{ __('You are logged in!') }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

`Product::get();` returns the following:

[image: get results]

I have searched everywhere and I somehow cannot find anybody with the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the problem? Sorry, it's not clear from your question. How are you trying to use the model...or in this case, the collection?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the screenshot of what it returns.
All I am trying to achieve is that I want to get data from my database on my webpage, and I have done this plenty of times but somehow it now returns the models instead of the data in the database

Comment: Do you want it to return multiple rows or just a single row? Please can you also show how you're trying to use it in your blade file :)

Comment: I have not added anything in my blade yet, but I've added it to the post I am trying to return multiple rows because returning a single row does work somehow.

Comment: "_but somehow it now returns the models instead of the data in the database_" I can't think of any Laravel version where this hasn't been standard behaviour. Those models contain your data, just display it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returning of a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections) is the expected behaviour for retrieving multiple models. Just loop through them in your blade file as you would if it were an array:

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::get();
    
    return view('home', compact('products'));
}
```

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            @foreach($products as $product)
                <li>{{ $product->Product_name }} - {{ $product->Product_price }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endsection
```

When you use `dd()` you'll see the actual model class. The models are designs so that you can access the row data from them directly, though e.g. `$product->Product_name` .

Comment: Allright this works, thanks a lot! but I still don't know how the dd does not show any data inside the models? because it used to show the data when I dd $products

Comment: The data for the model is actually stored in a property called `attributes`. If you open up one of the models, you see the data (you might need to `dd()` just one as `dd()` will only show so much data ) e.g. `dd($products->first())`.

Comment: Eloquent use magic methods to get/set the data and relationships for a model.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation! so the problem was I had too much records so the dd only showed data inside the model if I only had a few records showing.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)